# Javascript - Convert object with children to a steps-like array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops

I have an object:

```
const data = {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child',
          attributes: [{}],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
    },
  ],
};
```

And I want to convert them to a step-like array, where each element of the array (step) has elements from previous steps and one new child element.

**Example:**

```
const steps = [
 {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
 },
 {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
    },
  ],
 },
 {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child',
          attributes: [{}],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
 },
 {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
  children: [
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child',
          attributes: [{}],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'child',
      attributes: [{}],
    },
  ],
 }
]
```

I'm trying to do it using a recursive function, but have a problem with keeping parent elements and the right structure.

Let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not post any of the code that's having problems.

Comment: Your data appears to not be JSON. Are you sure it's not just a javascript object?

Comment: I have removed references to JSON

Comment: @Pointy, Thank you for your response. I did not find a solution that would solve the problem, so I did not add code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trees and recursions go hand in hand. Basically first I traverse the tree (`iterate`) pushing each item as I go along to an array (`result`). I also store each items parent.

Next step, I pass over that array by order, and reconstructing the `total` object by adding each item to its correct place. One by one. Then boom we clone it to a result  (`result_for_real`) array. Next item. Reconstruct. Clone. etc.

```js
const data = {
  name: 'root',
  attributes: [{}],
  children: [{
      name: 'child 1',
      attributes: [{}],
      children: [{
        name: 'grandchild',
        attributes: [{}],
      }],
    },
    {
      name: 'child 2',
      attributes: [{}],
    },
  ],
};

function create_steps(obj) {

  var result = []

  function iterate(obj, parent) {
    parent = parent || null
    var step = {
      name: obj.name,
      attributes: obj.attributes
    }
    result.push({step, parent});
    (obj.children || []).forEach(function(child) {
      iterate(child, step)
    });
  }
  iterate(obj)

  function clone(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
  }

  var result_for_real = [];
  var total = {}
  result.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.parent === null) {
      total = item.step;
    } else {
      item.parent.children = item.parent.children || []
      item.parent.children.push(item.step)
    }
    result_for_real.push(clone(total));
  })

  return result_for_real;
}

console.log(create_steps(data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```